# Oracle using reject unlimited clause

Tags: oracle

Can someone please modify the INSERT code below to use reject unlimited clause and log the errors in err$_t

I am running into syntax errors when I try to implement the following. Can the clause be used in this manner?

```
create table t(val1 NUMBER(4 ) );


 ALTER TABLE t
     ADD ( CONSTRAINT t_pk
   PRIMARY KEY (val1));


 exec dbms_errlog.create_error_log ( 't' );

 INSERT INTO T(val1)
 WITH cte AS
  (
  SELECT 1 from dual 
   UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 from dual
  )
  SELECT * from cte;
```

Comment: Your code works for me. (At least, it does when I uncomment the INSERT and add `log errors into err$_timeoff ('TEST') reject limit unlimited` at the end of that statement.) What exact error message are you getting? It might help to simplify the example so we can focus on the real problem - do you really need a separate `EMPLOYEES` table, all those columns, `CONNECT`, `MULTICAST`, and `dbms_random` to demonstrate the problem? The more you can minimize the example, the more likely someone can spot the problem.

Comment: I second @JonHeller your code works fine even after removing comments on insert statement and add log errors statement at the end.You need to post error codes

Comment: Thanks, reposted a simplified test CASE. Also for future use how do I format the code. I tried putting in spaces and not all the code was formatted

Answer (score 0):

Add the `log errors` clause at the end of the `INSERT` statement:

```
SQL> create table t(val1 number primary key);

Table created.

SQL> exec dbms_errlog.create_error_log ('t');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> insert into t(val1)
  2  with cte as
  3  (
  4      select 1 from dual
  5      union all
  6      select 1 from dual
  7  )
  8  select * from cte
  9  log errors into err$_t ('TEST')
 10  reject limit unlimited;

1 row created.

SQL> select count(*) rows_inserted from t;

ROWS_INSERTED
-------------
            1

SQL> select count(*) rows_with_errors from err$_t;

ROWS_WITH_ERRORS
----------------
               1

SQL>
```

Notice how I used used SQL*Plus to demonstrate the code. That program is *not* good for developing code, but it's helpful for creating simple, reproducible test cases. That tool is available to almost every Oracle developer, and it shows exactly how each command was run, including full error messages.

(One quick way to add syntax highlighting to your question is to select the code and click the "Code Sample" button, the two curly braces.)